# ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

Tags: express, redirect

I'm trying to get my server to redirect to another page in my 'public folder'. When I use:

```
response.redirect(path.join(__dirname, '../public/user_home.html'))
```

I get and error net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

On the client side I have:

```
$.get( "/user_home", function( data ) {console.log(data)};
```

I can't find anything about this error. Am I going about this incorrectly?

Comment: do you wrok with python server !!

Comment: The question is about express and nodejs. It is not about suggestions to use different technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your public folder is already available if you have static middleware configured in your app.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

You can use:

```
res.redirect("/user_home.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   response.redirect(path.join(__dirname, '../public/user_home.html'),safe=true)
```